# How can I add functions with different arguments and return types to a vector?

Tags: vector, rust

I'm trying add functions with different arguments to a vector.

```
fn f1() {
    println!("Hello, World!");
}
fn f2(s: &str) -> String {
    String::from(s)
}
fn f3(i: i32) {
    println!("{}", i);
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![f1, f3, f2];
}
```

But this gives the error:

> ```
> error[E0308]: mismatched types
>   --> src/main.rs:12:22
>    |
> 12 |     let v = vec![f1, f3, f2];
>    |                      ^^ incorrect number of function parameters
>    |
>    = note: expected type `fn() {f1}`
>            found fn item `fn(i32) {f3}`
> ```

Is there any way I can make this work?

Comment: What would you do with a vector of differently typed functions?

Comment: @ÖmerErden that would make sense for functions with the same signature (in which case they'd have the same type I think) but here not two functions are even called the same way.

Comment: @Masklinn that was just a guess, I don't know why OP wants this. But I believe making an abstraction like this to run random function is not a crime, even for a functions that have different signature from each other.

Comment: @ÖmerErden How would one actually run those functions, though? There's no way to call them when they have different signatures. It doesn't make sense to try. That's what mcarton's getting at.

Comment: @JohnKugelman i was thinking something like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8d08a16f5fa5bcdead8d0afe144cfe8f

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error happens because vectors are only meant to hold homogeneous data, i.e. every element of a vector has to be the same type. To solve this, you could for example use a vector of enums:

```
enum E {
    F1(fn()),
    F2(fn(&str) -> String),
    F3(fn(i: i32)),
}

fn f1() {
    println!("Hello, World!");
}
fn f2(s: &str) -> String {
    String::from(s)
}
fn f3(i: i32) {
    println!("{}", i);
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![E::F1(f1), E::F3(f3), E::F2(f2)];
    for func in v {
        match func {
            E::F1(f) => f(),
            E::F2(f) => println!("{}", f("foo")),
            E::F3(f) => f(2),
        } 
    }
}
```

> Output
>
> ```
> Hello, World!
> 2
> foo
> ```

Or you could use a container made specifically for storing heterogeneous data, aka a tuple:

```
fn main() {
    let v = (f1, f3, f2);
    v.0();
    v.1(2);
    println!("{}", v.2("foo"));
}
```

> Output
>
> ```
> Hello, World!
> 2
> foo
> ```